# Presenting ViewController whenever it receive a notify cause memory leaking

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ViewController` called `Home`, in `Home` `viewDidAppear` have a function `CheckStatus` that I need to call every time it received a specific notify.

So currently in `AppDelegate`, I call this code to present Home anytime the notify is received, which cause memory leaking and crashes:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! MainTabBarController
//Home is the first ViewController of the TabBar
self.window?.rootViewController = controller
```

What is the solution for this?

Updated `ViewDidAppear` and it's functions

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        setupTabbar() //setup tab bar UI
        self.locationService.getLocation()
        self.checkRequestStatus()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

func checkRequestStatus(){
        API.checkRequestStatus{ [weak self] json, error in
            if let error = error {
            }else {
                if let json = json {
                    let status = json[Const.STATUS_CODE].boolValue
                    if (!API.isSuccess(response: json)){
                        if (API.getErrorCode(response: json) == Const.INVALID_TOKEN){
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message".localized(), message: "You have logged in from another device. Please login again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK".localized(), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:
                                {(action:UIAlertAction!) in
                                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                                    print ("got here")
                                    defaults.set("", forKey: Const.Params.TOKEN)
                                    if self?.presentingViewController != nil {
                                        self?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                                            self?.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                                        })
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        self?.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                                    }
                            }))


                            self!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }

                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    if let currency : String = json[Const.CURRENCEY].rawString() {
                        defaults.set(currency, forKey: json[Const.CURRENCEY].rawString()!)
                    }
                    if let cancellation : Int = json[Const.CANCELLATION_FINE].intValue {
                        let str : String = String(cancellation)
                        defaults.set(str, forKey: Const.CANCELLATION_FINE)
                    }
                    if(status){
                        let requestDetail: RequestDetail = RequestDetail()
                        let jsonAry:[JSON]  = json[Const.DATA].arrayValue
                        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                        if jsonAry.count > 0 {
                            let driverData = jsonAry[0]
                            if driverData.exists() {
                                defaults.set(driverData["request_id"].stringValue, forKey: Const.Params.REQUEST_ID)
                                defaults.set(driverData["provider_id"].stringValue, forKey: Const.Params.DRIVER_ID)
                                requestDetail.initDriver(rqObj: driverData)
                            }
                            let invoiceAry:[JSON]  = json[Const.INVOICE].arrayValue
                            if invoiceAry.count > 0 {
                                let invoiceData = invoiceAry[0]
                                defaults.set(invoiceData.rawString(), forKey: Const.CURRENT_INVOICE_DATA)
                                requestDetail.initInvoice(rqObj: invoiceData)
                            }
                            self?.processStatus(json: json, tripStatus:requestDetail.tripStatus)
                        } else {
                            requestDetail.tripStatus = Const.NO_REQUEST
                            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                            defaults.set(Const.NO_REQUEST, forKey: Const.Params.REQUEST_ID)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code in `ViewController`? I think it has problems

Comment: @QuangDam it's pretty long and has a lot of unrelated stuff, the code is messy too. Can u tell me what kind of code you want too see so I can show you?

Comment: Let me check ’CheckStatus’.

Comment: I updated in the post

Comment: I think the root cause of your problem inside the closure of `UIAlertAction`. Although I saw you use the weak self above, you need to add it inside the `UIAlertAction` again and use the Instrument for checking leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are force-unwrapping self:

`self!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`  First see if your app still crashes when your replace the call with `self?.`.